# Trouble with adding to HashMap using arguments

Tags: java, hashmap, arguments

I am a newbie programmer and I can't figure out what is wrong with my addServer method. "details" is underlined and wants a semicolon next to it (I'm using Eclipse). I thought that I had set it up correctly but obviously I am wrong. It is called from the main and it's  purpose is to add to a hashmap of servers where the value of the hashmap consists of an instance of ServerDetails where two int fields are stored. All values are determined in the main. Before, serverList's value was just one integer and I didn't use an object and I got it to work fine.  If I need to show more code, please let me know.

```
public class ClientSummary {

private String clientID;
private String companyName;
private int totalNum;

private HashMap<String,ServerDetails> serverList;

public ClientSummary (){
    clientID = MainDisplay.getClientHolder();
    totalNum= MainDisplay.getNumAttackOnClient();
    serverList = new HashMap<String,ServerDetails>();
}



public void addServer(String x, int y, int z){
    ServerDetails details new ServerDetails(y,z);
    serverList.put(x, details);
}
 }
```

ServerDetails.java:

```
public class ServerDetails {

private int threatLevel;
private int numAttack;

ServerDetails(int y, int z){
    threatLevel = y;
    numAttack = z;
}
```

}

Comment: You are missing an `=` after `details`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void addServer(String x, int y, int z){
    ServerDetails details new ServerDetails(y,z);
    serverList.put(x, details);
}
```

Are you perhaps forgetting an equals sign in the second line?

Comment: oh my goodness, that's it. I guess that's what I get for working so late with no brain power left. Time to call it a night

Comment: Accept my answer before calling a night if it helped you! :)

Comment: @Zelfre I just got to wait out the remainder or the 10 minute limit before accepting an answer